# Regexp to match multi-line string

Tags: regex

I have this regexp:

```
^(?<FOOTER_TYPE>[ a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?(?<SEPARATOR>:)?(?<FOOTER>(?<=:)(.|[\r\n](?![\r\n]))*)?
```

Which I'm using to match text like:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: test
my multiline
string.

This is not matched
```

You can see the result here https://regex101.com/r/gGroPK/1

[image]

However, why is there the last `Group 4` ?

[image]

Comment: @anubhava https://regex101.com/r/gGroPK/1

Comment: Make it non-capturing, See demo: https://regex101.com/r/gGroPK/2

Comment: @anubhava oh my... Well, thanks! Feel free to post an answer and I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make last group non-capturing:

```
^(?<FOOTER_TYPE>[ a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?(?<SEPARATOR>:)?(?<FOOTER>(?<=:)(?:.|[\r\n](?![\r\n]))*)?
```

Make note of:

```
(?:.|[\r\n](?![\r\n]))*)?
```

`(?:` at the start makes this optional group non-capturing.

[Updated Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gGroPK/2)

Answer (score 0):

it is group 4 because the fourth parentheses you defined is:
`(.|[\r\n](?![\r\n]))*)`
it translate to

> "either dot, or the following regex"

and in the example you have, it ends on a dot.

> string.

so as regex is usually greedy, it captures dot as the forth group